# How do connect from Sequel to SQLite

Tags: ruby, sequel

My  SQLite database is located at `p:\StockSymbols.db`

I am trying to connect via the [sequel gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel), but it does not like it.

```
C:\Users\murth>irb irb(main):001:0> require 'sqlite3'
=> true irb(main):002:0> require 'sequel'
=> true irb(main):003:0> Sequel.sqlite('P:\\StockSymbols.db')
=> #<Sequel::SQLite::Database: {:adapter=>:sqlite, :database=>"P:\\StockSymbols.db"}> irb(main):004:0>  Sequel.connect("P:\\StockSymbols.db") URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): P:\StockSymbols.db
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/common.rb:231:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:34:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:121:in `connect'
        from (irb):4
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>' irb(main):005:0> Sequel.connect("sqllite:///P:/StockSymbols.db") Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/sqllite
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:88:in `load_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:17:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:36:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-5.13.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:121:in `connect'
        from (irb):5
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have sqlite3 installed too. You probably need to `require 'sqlite3'` too in the same irb session before `Sequel.connect`.

Also, rename the db using snake_case. Just a convention.

```
require 'sequel'
require 'sqlite3'

DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://your_db.db') # ./your_db.db
```

Comment: yes i do have sqlite3 and updated teh code above. I still have the same issue. I am guessing that it has somethign to do with how i connect. My database is in p:
how do i create a Sequel.connect using a file name in windows?

Comment: @junkone try moving your db into the same working directory as your project.

Comment: tried that too. for eg.irb(main):025:0> File.exists?("StockSymbols.db")
=> true
irb(main):026:0> FileUtils.pwd
=> "P:/"
irb(main):027:0> File.exists?("StockSymbols.db")
=> true
irb(main):028:0> Sequel.connect("sqllite:////StockSymbols.db")
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/sqllite
        from C:/Ruby24-

Comment: @junkone four forward slashes? shouldn't that be 2 or 3?